# getJson is sending queryString in lowercase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string, getjson, uppercase, lowercase

I'm doing a getJson call in a local website, but into the URL i'm sending a queryString, the problem happends when the call gets to the server and I realize that the query string was in lowercase but I need it to be in UpperCase, the wierd thing is that this happends from one day to another because this functionality was programed one year ago but today is not working, I proved it in other machines and they worked as we expected but not in my laptop and i haven't done any change on the getJson, it is even wierder if I say that ALL my getJson calls are being sended in lowercase!! (I debuged and all getJson is in lowercase). could it be a problem with anything between the getJsons and my local MVC application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with 301 redirection that was converting all the letters of the url into lowercase to make the redirection.